# Copying newlines in JavaScript alert to clipboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, newline, alert

Is this simply a browser issue or am I formatting content wrong?

I'm calling `alert("This\nis\na\ntest");` and then pressing `Ctrl + C` to copy the contents of the alert message to my clipboard. This is working, except that the text copied to my clipboard doesn't contain the newlines. I've tried `\r\n` as well and although it prints the newlines in my alert box, they don't get copied to the clipboard in Chrome on Windows 8.

Is there a newline character I'm not using or is this a limitation I can't fix?

See this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oscsy07b/1/

Thanks.

Comment: Using Chrome i cant copy text from alert, how you're doing that? O_o

Comment: Actually, the text is already "selected". While an alert box is open, you should be able to hit whatever shortcut you use to copy and it'll copy the contents of the alert message to the clipboard, e.g. Ctrl + C or Cmd + C.

Comment: worked for me to copy from Firefox to Notepad++ - actually with 2 newlines, not just 1..

Comment: I've check this by fiefox 34 and when paste code in notepat, show with new lines

Comment: Okay, so this might specifically be a Chrome issue then.

Comment: >`Actually, the text is already "selected"`: Wow, that's awesome, i didn't know that, thanks :D

Comment: Seems to be Chrome-specific. It works fine for me in IE, but not in Chrome (using Windows 8).